# PromQL min_over_time + predict_linear / peaks monitoring

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana, promql

## Context

The application running on the monitored disk intermittently doubles the amount of space it requires, causing disk utilization peaks that only last for a few seconds / minutes.

If the storage space is not enough to account for those  peaks, the applications storage gets corrupted.

The monitoring examples I found only account for the usual amount of storage used, and sees the peaks as temporarily glitches.

[image]

## What I tried (min_over_time + predict_linear : KO :-( )

I tried to use `min_over_time(...[12h])` along with `predict_linear`, but it's not working due to a type error :

I currently have the following PromQL :
`predict_linear(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{job="nodeexporter",fstype!=""}[6h]`

but what I actually want to monitor is the `min_over_time(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{job="nodeexporter",fstype!=""}[12h])` instead of `node_filesystem_avail_bytes{job="nodeexporter",fstype!=""}` , to account for sporadic disk utilisation peaks.
I thought it make sense, but unfortunately the following is not an accepted PromQL query:

```
predict_linear(min_over_time(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{job="nodeexporter",fstype!=""}[12h])[6h], 4*60*60)
```

Error :

```
Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:94: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors
```

## questions

- How would you monitor the disk utilization to take those peaks into account ?
- How would you use min_over_time + predict_linear together ?

Thanks in advance for any clue or suggestion !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `:5m` aftet `6h` in the second square brackets. This enables [subquery mode](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/), which instructs Prometheus to execute the inner query (e.g. `min_over_time(...)` on the given time range per every 5 minute step and then to execute the outer query (e.g. `predict_linear(...)` on top of results returned by inner query.

Comment: Hello @valyala, thanks a lot !

I managed to modify my query with your suggestion and this is an accepted result :
```predict_linear(min_over_time(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{job="nodeexporter",fstype!=""}[12h])[6h:5m], 4*60*60)```